# Passing char * to function returns different results than passing char []?

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers

I am writing a function in C to get the next word from a string (*s) and copy it into the buffer (*w). It returns the first char of the word.

It works fine when the input string is a char pointer (char *text), but when I change the type to a char array (char [MAXTEXT]) the program crashes.

This is confusing me, as I thought the compiler 'decayed' char arrays into char pointers anyway. To my belief, whether the input is a char pointer or a char array shouldn't make a difference?

(The declaration is at line 10 `char *text = "This should return the first word";`, which crashes when changed to `char text[MAXTEXT] = "This should return the first word";`)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAXTEXT 1000

int getword(char *inp, char *out, int lim);

void main()
{
    char *text = "This should return the first word";
    char *word;
    int i, c;

    printf("%c", getword(text, word, MAXTEXT));
    printf("%s", word);
}

int getword(char *s, char *w, int lim)
{
    static int bufp = 0;
    char c;
    char *word = w;

    while (isspace(c = s[bufp++]));

    if (c != EOF)
        *w++ = c;
    else if (!isalpha(c))
    {
        *w = '\0';
        return c;
    };

    for (; --lim > 0; bufp++)
        if (isalpha(c = s[bufp]) || c == '\'')
            *w++ = s[bufp];
        else
            break;
    *w = '\0';
    return word[0];
}
```

Comment: When you declare `word` as a pointer, *where does it point?*

Comment: Nowhere yet? When I set declarations am I not simply setting aside memory for the initialization of a pointer that points to a char? The initialization happens inside the getword() function.

Comment: Also, unless you explicitly put `EOF` into the `text` buffer, then it will never contain a characters with that value. And if you do, then you have the problem with `EOF` being an *`int`* and not a char, and that there are chances that `(char)EOF != EOF` (it depends on if `char` is `unsigned` or not, which is compiler-specific). There's a reason the standard I/O character functions return an `int` and not a `char`.

Comment: Regarding `word`, you never make it point *anywhere* which means its value will be *indeterminate* and when you dereference it you will have *undefined behavior*. Who knows where you will write the characters? Either make it an array, or dynamically allocate memory for it.

Comment: There's no initialization of the parameter w in getword and even if there were, it'd initialize the local variable w, not the calling function's word variable, since you pass word by value.

Comment: Alright, so the declaration of word has to be a character array, otherwise the pointer has nothing to point to? Just tried it and it works. But now I'm wondering how it even worked before?

Comment: I think you should change `char *word;` to `char word[MAXTEXT];`.

Comment: Undefined behavior is undefined. It may seemingly "work", until it doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Was searching around but couldn't find anything that helped me understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that for the pointer `word`, you haven't allocated any memory. Simply allocating memory will fix the problem.
Your array implementation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define MAXTEXT 1000

char getword(char *inp, char *out, int lim);

int main()
{
    char text[100],word[100];
    // char *text = (char*)calloc(100,sizeof(char));
    strcpy(text,"This should return the first word");
    // char *word = (char*)calloc(100,sizeof(char));
    int i, c;

    printf("%c", getword(text, word, MAXTEXT));
    // printf("%s", text);
    return 0;
}

char getword(char *s, char *w, int lim)
{
    static int bufp = 0;
    char c;
    char *word = w;

    while (isspace(c = s[bufp++]));

    if (c != EOF)
        *w++ = c;
    else if (!isalpha(c))
    {
        *w = '\0';
        return c;
    };

    for (; --lim > 0; bufp++)
        if (isalpha(c = s[bufp]) || c == '\'')
            *w++ = s[bufp];
        else
            break;
    *w = '\0';
    return word[0];
}
```